# How add cms page tab with dynamic contant in magento

Tags: php, magento

please help me,
How to add cms page tab with fully dynamic contant and easy manage from admin and i want to add three ya four field for data like

- Image upload
- Title and
- Description

see below image link to understand you.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssgjp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these blogs, this will be helpfull:

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-add-jquery-tabs-in-cms-page/

http://www.magentoforum.com/blogs/useful-tips-and-articles/608-

Comment: you right dud but i want to full dynamically it means all in data to manage by admin like upload image option, title text box, and for description magento editor.

Comment: same as like blog see two below images shreen short http://i.stack.imgur.com/W1HAU.png    http://i.stack.imgur.com/aMR1G.jpg